# Como extraer una cadena dentro de un string en c?

Tags: array, c, string

Tengo la siguiente cadena:

```
 char url[]="table=peliculas/&name=lo_que_sea.pdf"
```

quiero almacenar "lo_que_sea.pdf" en una variable como extraria ese texto de mi string ????

Comment: Depende de qué datos puedas darnos sobre la cadena en cuestión. ¿Lo que quieres extraer está siempre separado por un `=` del resto? ¿Siempre es el último `=` que aparece en la cadena?

Comment: siiii .............he probado con split pero nada, tambien van siempre detras de name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más sencillo es buscar la dirección de memoria donde está guardado el último `=` de la cadena (usando `strrchr()`) y copiar a otra cadena lo que hay a partir de ese punto (usando por ejemplo `strdup()`).

Por ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char url[]="table=peliculas/&name=lo_que_sea.pdf";
  char *nombre_fichero;
  char *pos_igual;

  pos_igual = strrchr(url, '=');
  if (pos_igual == 0) {
    printf("La URL no tiene el formato esperado\n");
  } else {
    nombre_fichero = strdup(pos_igual+1);
    printf("Nombre del fichero: %s\n", nombre_fichero);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

### Sin punteros (bueno, casi)

La solución anterior usa punteros para dos cosas:

1. Para encontrar la posición de memoria dentro de la url donde está guardado el último `=`. Las posiciones de memoria deben guardarse en punteros.
2. Para obtener una copia de la parte que contiene el nombre del fichero. Las copias deben hacerse a otra posición de la memoria, cuyo tamaño no sabemos de antemano por que no sabemos cuántas letras tendrá el nombre del fichero, así que no podemos reservar un array para ello. La función `strdup()` "duplica" una cadena (o subcadena en este caso) haciendo espacio para la nueva, y retornando la dirección de memoria donde la ha copiado. Esta dirección es de nuevo un puntero.

Se pueden eliminar los punteros si:

1. Programamos nuestra propia función para buscar el `=`, que en lugar de retornar la dirección donde está, retorne el índice (entero) dentro del array.
2. No sacamos copia del nombre de fichero, sino solo lo imprimimos.

Esta solución hace eso:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int indice_del_ultimo(char cadena[], char buscar) {
  int i;

  for (i=strlen(cadena); i>=0; i--) {
    if (cadena[i] == buscar)
      return i;
  }
  return -1; // No se ha encontrado
}

int main() {
  char url[]="table=peliculas/&name=lo_que_sea.pdf";
  //char nombre_fichero[];
  int pos_igual;

  pos_igual = indice_del_ultimo(url, '=');
  if (pos_igual == -1) {
    printf("La URL no tiene el formato esperado\n");
  } else {
    printf("Nombre del fichero: %s\n", url+pos_igual+1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Aunque no se han usado aparentemente punteros (no hay variables de tipo `char*`) en realidad sí hay aritmética de punteros en la expresión `url+pos_igual+1`, pues el resultado de eso es una dirección de memoria (en concreto, la dirección donde está la letra siguiente al `=` que encontramos en la URL).

Comment: vale pero no entiendo mui bien lo de * eso se podria poner un []

Comment: @ortiga No. Aunque en muchos sitios arrays y punteros son intercambiables, no son lo mismo. En este caso lo que retorna `strrchr()` es un puntero y no puede asignarse a una variable de tipo array (porque las variables tipo array no pueden cambiar a dónde "apuntan").

Comment: y con split se podria hacer ???

Comment: @ortiga ¿Qué `split()`? C no tiene esa función. Lo más parecido es `strtok()`, pero si los punteros te lían, el `strtok()` ni te cuento... Además ya que la cadena tiene varios iguales tendrías que iterar por ellos y detectar cuándo llegaste al último. Lo veo mucho más complejo. Si fuera python sería otra cosa, claro